How to Implement Zoom In/Out Functionality in CustomTkinter GUI
I'm trying to add zoom in/out functionality to my customtkinter GUI on a Raspberry Pi. Due to the lack of built-in support for scaling widgets in customtkinter, I'm struggling to achieve this. Has anyone successfully implemented zoom functionality in a customtkinter application, and can you provide guidance or examples on how to dynamically resize and reposition widgets based on user input? Your help would be greatly appreciated!
I attempted to manually adjust the size and placement of all widgets based on user input. However, this approach proved to be complex and prone to errors, making it difficult to maintain the layout and functionality of the GUI.
I expect to find a more streamlined method or a built-in function to handle zoom functionality, similar to pinch-to-zoom on mobile applications, where the entire interface scales dynamically.

Without knowing more about your application it's impossible to say. For example. zooming in a text widget in a notepad-type app is trivial. Zooming things on a canvas isn't too difficult either. However, having multiple forms with multiple types of widgets can be challenging.

You can achieve a zoom effect by programmatically adjusting the size and position of widgets in response to user input. (Such as mouse scroll events or button presses.)
Here’s a conceptual approach to implement zoom functionality:

1. Scale Factor Calculation: Define a scale factor that determines the degree of zoom. This factor will be used to scale the dimensions of
the widgets.


2. Adjust Widget Dimensions and Positions: For each widget in your GUI, you need to:

Calculate the new size based on the scale factor.
Reposition the widget to maintain the layout consistency.



3. Event Binding: Bind the zoom in/out actions to user events like mouse scroll or button clicks.

import customtkinter as ctk
import tkinter as tk

class ZoomableApp(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.zoom_factor = 1.0 # controls zoom level
        self.zoom_increment = 0.1
    # frame
        self.frame = ctk.CTkFrame(self)
        self.frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        
    # excample widgets
        self.label = ctk.CTkLabel(self.frame, text="Zoomable Label", font=("Arial", 20))
        self.label.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor="center")
        
        self.button = ctk.CTkButton(self.frame, text="Zoomable Button")
        self.button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.6, anchor="center")
        
    # binds mouse wheel / +- for to zoom
        self.bind("<MouseWheel>", self.zoom)
        self.bind("<KeyPress-+>", self.zoom_in)
        self.bind("<KeyPress-minus>", self.zoom_out)
    
    def zoom(self, event):
        if event.delta > 0:
            self.zoom_in(event)
        else:
            self.zoom_out(event)
    
    def zoom_in(self, event):
        self.set_zoom(self.zoom_factor + self.zoom_increment)
    
    def zoom_out(self, event):
        self.set_zoom(self.zoom_factor - self.zoom_increment)
    
    def set_zoom(self, new_zoom_factor):
        if 0.5 <= new_zoom_factor <= 2.0:  # limits for zoom
            self.zoom_factor = new_zoom_factor
            self.update_widgets()
    # widgets get adjusted according to new zoom factor 
    def update_widgets(self): 
        new_font_size = int(20 * self.zoom_factor)
        self.label.configure(font=("Arial", new_font_size))
        
        self.button.configure(width=int(100 * self.zoom_factor), height=int(30 * self.zoom_factor))

        self.label.place_configure(relx=0.5, rely=0.5)
        self.button.place_configure(relx=0.5, rely=0.6)
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = ZoomableApp()
    app.mainloop()


Do you need the 2 place_configure calls in update_widgets? Shouldn't they be unnecessary as the widgets are already in that position

@TheLizzard You're right, the widgets are place using absolute postioning, the calls are not necessary if the widgets are not changing their positions.

I would say that if you use the geometry managers (pack, place, and grid) correctly, you'll never need to adjust the size of widgets. Those geometry managers can be configured to automatically resize widgets when things change.
